# Event listener functions changing when using React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, react-hooks, usecallback

I have a component that uses event listeners in several places through `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. It's not sufficient to use component methods like `onMouseMove` because I need to detect events outside the component as well.

I use hooks in the component, several of which have the dependency-array at the end, in particular `useCallback(eventFunction, dependencies)` with the event functions to be used with the listeners. The dependencies are typically stateful variables declared using `useState`.

From what I can tell, the identity of the function is significant in `add/remove` `EventListener`, so that if the function changes in between it doesn't work. At first i tried managing the hooks so that the event functions didn't change identity between `add` and `remove` but that quickly became unwieldy with the functions' dependency on state.

So in the end I came up with the following pattern: Since the setter-function (the second input parameter to `useState`) gets the current state as an argument, I can have event functions that never change after first render (do we still call this mount?) but still have access to up-to-date stateful variables. An example:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(() => {
    setState((currentState) => {
      // ... do something that involves currentState ...
      return currentState;
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [/* ... some parameters here ... */]);

  // ... more effects etc ...

  return <span>test</span>;
};
```

(This is a much simplified illustration).

This seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if it feels quite right - using a setter function that never changes the state but just as a hack to access the current state.

Also, for event functions that require several state variables I have to nest the setter calls.

Is there another pattern that could handle this situation in a nicer way?

Comment: Could you not just use `state` here as *that is* the current state. Are you setting state to trigger react to re-render a component?

Comment: If I do that, I have to make sure that `onMouseMove` is updated when `state` changes, i.e. supply `state` in the dependency array. And then the call to `removeEventListener` will not work because it's no longer the same effect function

Comment: See [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#use-render-props-for-cross-cutting-concerns) as an alternative.

Comment: Something doesn't quite add up, `onMouseMove` should have only a dependency on the mouse moving in whichever element the event listener is attached to, window here. What is the goal here?

Comment: The goal is a component that allows drag-selecting children components, and also only renders a window of the latter depending on scroll. `onMouseMove` depends, among other things, on a list of references to the children components (that is used to check where they are, using `getBoundingClientRect`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> From what I can tell, the identity of the function is significant in add/remove EventListener, so that if the function changes in between it doesn't work.

While this is true, we do not have to go the extreme of arranging for even function not to change identity at all.

Simple steps will be:
Declare event function using `useCallback` - dependency list of `useCallback` should include all the stateful variables that your function depends on.

Use `useEffect` to add the event listener. Return cleanup function that will remove the event listener. Dependency list of `useEffect` should include the event listener function itself, in addition to any other stateful variable your effect function might be using.

This way, when any of stateful variable used by event listener changes, even listener's identity changes, which will trigger running of the effect, but before running the effect cleanup function returned by previous run of the effect will be run, properly removing old event listener before adding the new one.

Something on the lines of:

```
const Component = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState();

    const eventListner = useCallback(() => {
        console.log(state); // use the stateful variable in event listener
    }, [state]);

    useEffect(() => {
        el.addEventListner('someEvent', eventListner);
        return () => el.removeEventListener('someEvent', eventListner);
    }, [eventListener]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ckedar 's solution can solve this question, but it has performance problem, when the eventListener change, react will remove and addEvent on the dom。

you can use `useRef()` instead `useState()`,if you want listen state change, you can use `useStateRef()`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export default function useStateRef(initialValue:any): Array<any>{
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const ref = useRef(value);
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  },[value])
  return [value,setValue,ref];
}
```